# How to get the count of inputs (complaints) received per day on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, graph, frequency, trello, typeform

[Repeating dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5dyt.png)

I receive n number of complaints via Typeform and have linked the typeform with google sheets.

For now, I have the data of all those complaints received from February 16 to March 16.
The number of complaints i received per day vary, like 5 complaints of Feb 16th, 2 on 17th , 7-8 on 18th, you get the gist.

I would like to make a report using Bar graph which displays a simple formation of number of complaints received per day (ex. 5,10,15) on the vertical axis by dates (eg. Feb 14, Feb 15, Feb 16) in the horizontal axis.

That is all!

EDIT: I now have the dates being repeated in the graph , Can someone help me with the dates not being repeated ? thanks

Comment: Hey, for sure. I have shared it above in the name of repeating dates. Feel free to take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `QUERY()` function to get a distinct list of dates and the `COUNT` aggregation function to find the count of complaints.

More info in the official [Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) and (in my opinion better) more info from Ben Collins [here](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/)

Comment: So, I tried this and I almost got what I want. 
I have the dates being repeated.
Can you please help me with it?

I want 16th, 17th, 18th be only once on the horizontal line

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem when I can't see what you are seeing. Most likely you are not grouping this correctly, or there's a chance that the chart is interpreting the dates a bit strangely. Do you have the dates showing multiple times in the table?

Answer (score 0):

What about trying the below:

Create another table with dates and sum where days will contain the unique values for each date using:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A19)
```

Where *A2:A19* is the range where your duplicate dates are.

As for the sum of values, you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(A2:A19,unique(A2:A19),B2:B19))
```

Where *'A2:A19'* is the range for dates and *'B2:B19'* is the range for values.

Then you proceed to create your chart.

##### Something to consider:

Your dates include time stamps, which will make the dates different and therefore be repeated even after using unique(), so if time is important keep this in mind or remove it.